# TYPO3 ckeditor table - add div for responsive class

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, typo3, typo3-11.x

In the TYPO3 ckeditor is the default html output:

```
<table class="table">
   ...
</table>
```

for the responsive bootstrap table i need a  wrap around the  Tag:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 5 responsive table:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/tables/#responsive-tables

How can i add a  wrap ?

i add this "ckeditor externalPlugins" for table:
https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Resources/Public/CKEditor/Plugins/Table/plugin.js

maybe i could add a wrap to the frontend there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TypoScript to add the necessary wrapper to the frontend:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE {
    externalBlocks {
        table {
            stdWrap {
                wrap = <div class="table-responsive">|</div>
            }
        }
}
```

This will then apply to all `<table>` HTML elements inside RTE fields.

The Bootstrap Package works the same way: https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/ContentElement/Helper/ParseFunc.typoscript#L91

Answer (score 1):

Make a config.yaml line:

```
externalPlugins:
    table_wrapper: {resource: "EXT:my_ext/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Plugins/wrapper.js"}
```

With js:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('table_wrapper', { 
    init: function (editor) {
        editor.on('insertElement', function (event) {
            if (event.data.getName() === 'table') {
                var div = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('div').addClass('table-responsive'); // Create a new div element to use as a wrapper.
                event.data.appendTo(div); // Append the original element to the new wrapper.
                event.data = div; // Replace the original element with the wrapper.
            }
        }, null, null, 1);
    }
});
```

Also make sure the tags are allowed etc.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the nice Solution!

but it dont work, i do this:

RTE Config:

```
editor:
  externalPlugins:
    table_responsive: { resource: "EXT:rlp_base/Resources/Public/RTE/Plugins/Table.js" }
    table_wrap: {resource: "EXT:rlp_base/Resources/Public/RTE/Plugins/TableWrap.js"}
```

and this:

```
editor:
  ...
  config:
    ...
    extraPlugins:
      - justify
      - table_responsive
      - table_wrap
```

in the TableWrap.js is this:

```
'use strict';

(function() {

    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('table_wrap', {
        init: function (editor) {
            editor.on('insertElement', function (event) {
                if (event.data.getName() === 'table') {
                    var div = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('div').addClass('table-responsive'); // Create a new div element to use as a wrapper.
                    event.data.appendTo(div); // Append the original element to the new wrapper.
                    event.data = div; // Replace the original element with the wrapper.
                }
            }, null, null, 1);
        }
    });

})();
```

Example like this:  https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Resources/Public/CKEditor/Plugins/Table/plugin.js

my Frontend HTML output is this:

```
<div class="ce-bodytext">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody><tr>
      ...
    </tr></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Maybe it's another javascript error?